# AngularJs : style a column in Ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I want to style a column in ag-grid, using AngularJs (I want it to look like hyperlinks, maybe even with visited/unvisited colo(u)rs). The particular style is not important; I just want to know how to style a column. Static styling is fine; I don't need dynamic styling.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
columnDefs: [{ headerName: "Candidate", 
               field: "candidate_name", 
               sortable: true, 
               cellStyle: function(params) {return {color: 'red'}}},
```

I am unsure how to do it without the callback, but I can live with this.